# Of whose wealth is the king regarded to be the lord of?

Tags: kings

It is said that the king owns the wealth of some people. Who are those people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any property that is abandoned in the state belongs to the king.

> Any of these is lost to the owner when it is used by someone else
> continuously for ten years. 18 But they also quote a verse to the
> contrary: A pledge, a boundary, property of minors, an open deposit, a
> sealed deposit, women, and the property of the king or a vedic scholar
> are not lost to the owner by being used by someone else. 19
> **Abandoned property belongs to the king**. 20 If it is not abandoned, the king, together with ministers and city folk, should administer the
> property
>
> *Dharmasutras of Vashishta 16.17-16.20*

In case, if no legal heirs are present for a particular property, then that also is owned by the king except if it belongs to a Brahmin.

> In the absence of an heir belonging to the first six types of sons,
> people belonging to the same ancestry or those taking the place of
> sons should divide the estate of the deceased; 82 in the absence of
> these, the teacher and the resident pupil should take the estate; 83
> **and in their absence, the king. 84 The king, however, should not take the estate of a Brahmin; 85 the property of a Brahmin is dreadful
> poison.** 86
>
> *17.81-17.86*

In a similar manner a treasure trove is also owned by the king.

> Ownership is established by inheritance, purchase, partition,
> possession, and discovery; 40 additionally, acceptance for Brahmins,
> 41 conquest for Ksatriyas, 42 and wages for Vais´yas and ´Sudras.
> 43 **A treasure-trove is the property of the king, 44 except when it
> is found by an upright Brahmin.** 45 According to some, even a
> non-Brahmin who discloses a find should receive onesixth. 46 When
> property is stolen by thieves, the king should recover it and return
> it to its rightful owner 47 or pay compensation from his treasury. 48
> He should keep the property of children safely until they reach the
> legal age or have completed their studies.
>
> *Dharmasutras of Gautama 10.39-10.48*